# how to check if any removable media connect to remote host

Tags: linux, python

i need to check if any USB or removable media is connected to my network or sub net . what i am doing right now i make a simple client/server model which send message to each other what i want the client USB information by running lsusb or any other command after that it will sends the command output to server how can i achieve this or is there any better way to do this . I am using Linux for both client/server . This is my client side code. what i change in it so that client sends his log to server.

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

#Wait for incoming data from server
#.decode is used to turn the message in bytes to a string
def receive(socket, signal):
    while signal:
        try:
            data = socket.recv(32)
            print(str(data.decode("utf-8")))
        except:
            print("You have been disconnected from the server")
            signal = False
            break

#Get host and port
host = input("Host: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))

#Attempt connection to server
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
except:
    print("Could not make a connection to the server")
    input("Press enter to quit")
    sys.exit(0)

#Create new thread to wait for data
receiveThread = threading.Thread(target = receive, args = (sock, True))
receiveThread.start()

#Send data to server
#str.encode is used to turn the string message into bytes so it can be sent across the network
while True:
    message = input()
    sock.sendall(str.encode(message))
```

Comment: But *USB or removable media* is not connected to the network, it's connected to a computer than can share its contents to other computers in the network.

Comment: Can you give more info on your current solution? It might be easier to build on top of it. It is not clear if you want to check (query a host to see if has removable media attached) or report (a host telling a server that it now has removable media connected to it).

Comment: hi, i will put my code here what i am trying to do is the client send his log's or sysinfo where i check the removable media is attached to client or not from his log if it is then server auto send the message to client to disconnect it , for the time being i just want client's log to server side after every 2 min.